# Create dynamic column based on data in other columns

Tags: python, pandas

Original data:

```
Data Set  
Day  100 200 300 400
1    2   4   6   8
2    3   5   7   9
3    4   6   8   10
```

Desired output:

```
Day  Lookup Val  Value
1    100         2
2    400         9
3    200         6
```

Basically trying to figure out how to create the second dataframe that queries the first based on the lookup value provided. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check with lookup https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html

Answer (score 0):

Below is one of the possible solutions. For a very large data frames it may be slow, but should work fine with average size data. I am assuming that the lookup info is loaded into some data frame. Please let me know if you have questions.

```
days = [1,2,3]
_100 = [2,3,4]
_200 = [4,5,6]
_300 = [6,7,8]
_400 = [8,9,10]
# this is your actual data
df = pd.DataFrame({"Day":days, "100": _100, "200": _200, "300": _300, "400": _400})
df.set_index("Day", inplace=True)
days = [1,2,3]
lookup = [100,400,200]
#this is your look up table
dfLookup = pd.DataFrame({"Day":days, "Lookup Val": lookup})
def get_value(row):
    row_id = row["Day"]
    lookup_id = str(row["Lookup Val"])
    dfRow = df.loc[row_id].copy()
    dfRow = pd.DataFrame(dfRow)
    dfRow.reset_index(inplace=True)
    dfRow.columns = ["lookup", "values"]
    dictLookUp = dict(zip(dfRow["lookup"], dfRow["values"]))
    value = dictLookUp[lookup_id]
    dfRow = None
    return value

dfLookup["Value"] = dfLookup.apply(lambda row: get_value(row), axis=1)
```